# Passing parameters to via GetAsync()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an API that I want to test.  This is the signature of one method...

```
[HttpGet("{param}")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string param, string param2)
{
...
}
```

In the test project I structure the call this way...

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string uri = "http://localhost:63779/api/controller_name/param/";
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
```

param is part of the route but how do I get param2 to the method?

Comment: use query string it it's a get `?param=foo&param2=bar`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass `param2` as query string ti the server. The client code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string uri = "http://localhost:63779/api/controller_name/param/?param2=SOME_VALUE";
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
```

Comment: Adding, We could use string interpolation, ex:
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string param2 = "someValue";
string uri = $"http://localhost:63779/api/controller_name/param/?param2={param2 }";
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

ref:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated